# Transform an RDD of n elements into an RDD of single element

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of strings like below

```
val rdd1: RDD[String] = RDD("a","b","c","d")
```

I want to concatenate the elements of the above RDD and transform it into an RDD of single element like below

```
RDD("a,b,c,d")
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: do you really want an `RDD` of a single element? What's the value in using a _distributed_ collection if it only has one item? If not, and you're just interested in that single record, you can call `rdd1.collect().mkString(",")`

Comment: I wanted to store the result in HDFS using the rdd saveAsTextFile method. That's the reason why I wanted to transform it into another RDD.

Comment: @raHul There's no need to do this then. If you just squash all of you data into a single-valued RDD, as already mentioned, there's no point in using a distributed processing framework. `saveAsTextFile` will take care of that for you and distribute your results on HDFS.

Comment: In my use case I wanted to store the result as a single record in a hive table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `glom` function:

```
val res: RDD[Array[String]] = RDD("a","b","c","d").glom
// > res = RDD(Array("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

You can then convert the array into a string using the `mkString` function.